# How do find time at execution of line in C

Tags: c, time

I'm trying to print the time in seconds at when the print is executed.

This is what I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void printTime(clock_t start){
    clock_t stop = clock();
    double time = (double)(stop-start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("This is printed at time %f.\n", time);
}

int main(){
    clock_t start = clock();
    sleep(3);
    printTime(start);
    return 0;
}
```

It would always print the time as 0.000000

Comment: If you can use POSIX, `clock_gettime` can be used for this.

Comment: `"%e"` is more informative than `"%f"` .

Comment: @chux: that's highly subjective and not really relevant.

Comment: Sorry about the wrong duplicate first :P

Comment: It worked with clock_gettime but is there another way to do this?

Comment: The trouble is that `sleep(3);` doesn't use very much processor time, yet that's what the `clock()` function measures:

_The `clock()` function determines the amount of processor time used since the invocation of the calling
     process, measured in `CLOCKS_PER_SEC`s of a second._  You can use `clock_gettime()` or perhaps `gettimeofday()` to get elapsed time, which is what you want to measure.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler the duplicate could use that explanation in one answer :P

Comment: Your windows alternative to `clock_gettime` is `QueryPerformanceCounter`.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: I've added an answer that is fairly comprehensive for the Unix interfaces.